# Shopify Dashing auth_token

Tags: dashing

I've followed this tutorial (and some others) to start working with shopify's dashing:

http://www.slideshare.net/larrycai/learn-dashing-widget-in-90-minutes

But when dashing web server is up and running, I hit localhost:3030/ instead of the dashing widgets, I only get the message:

Try this: curl -d '{ "auth_token": "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN", "text": "Hey, Look what I can do!" }' \localhost:3030/widgets/welcome

How can I fix this?

Edit: I've read somewhere that installing node.js can help, but it didn't.

Comment: Can u describe more for your env ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, are you running Dashing on windows? Also, what version of Ruby and Ruby dev kit? I followed this while doing mine [Link](http://3man.co.za/?p=6).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
You have to install Ruby DevKit
Run this command line

`ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb review
ruby dk.rb install`

Installing nodeJS and this will work.